# Insert Line break with mysql UPDATE

Tags: javascript, mysql

im using JSON.stringify and my stringified variable is:

```
{"ops":[{"insert":"drfsdfgg sdfg sdg \ns\ndfg\ndf\nsg\nsdfg\n"}]}
```

But when I do an UPDATE, the data is like that in mysql database:

```js
{"ops":[{"insert":"drfsdfgg sdfg sdg 
s
dfg
df
sg
sdfg
"}]}
```

I would like preserve all \n like the INSERT! ( yes INSERT WORKS )

the SQL query:

```js
 connection.query("UPDATE products SET description ='" + req.body.description + "' WHERE id = " + req.body.id, function (error, results, fields) {
  if (!!error) {
   console.log('erreur');
  } else {
   // console.log(results);
   res.json();
  };
 });
```

Comment: **WARNING**: Always escape any arbitrary data in your query by using *placeholder values*. Inlining `req.body.description` here is a huge [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com/). Most database drivers for Node have placeholder support built-in.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, all is about the SQL syntax. Thank you so much to me and my brain power.

```js
 connection.query("UPDATE products SET description = ? WHERE id = " + req.body.id, [req.body.description], function (error, results, fields) {
  if (!!error) {
   console.log('erreur');
  } else {
   // console.log(results);
   res.json();
  };
 });
```

Comment: Set both of these to placeholder values and it's actually fixed. This is a half fix.

Comment: It's also not clear why you do `if (!!error)` when `if (error)` would have the same result. The `!!` convention is used to force cast to a boolean, something only relevant if you actually assign that value to something or return it.